# Differentiate Data or Cable/DSL visitor on a Website

Tags: data

I have a professional issue with this matter, is it technically possible to know if a visitor on my website is connected via mobile data or home/cable/DSL?

I got complete IP ranges of all carriers in my country and thought about using a reverse DNS lookup on connection, but maybe it's not the best way to do that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is carrier is also ISP in your country? You can know ISP by the IP, but carrier can be different (technically). Another question is each carrier uses only one access method ? if the answers yes&yes, you probably not need for reverse DNS, just check source IP of the connection.
This does not cover cases when users are using VPNs or proxies of course, so you need to be aware that checking source IP is not 100% trustworthy.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, no. You are asking about a layer-1 connection that is only known or relevant on the layer-1 link. There is nothing about layer-1 that is carried into the upper network layers.

It may be possible to discover the ISP that owns the IP address used, but that is not definitive, especially where the owner provides mobile, home, and business Internet services, or the ISP is a smaller home ISP that uses IP address blocks from a larger business ISP.